# how to compare numbers in string with string?

Tags: java

i have array which is:

```
String[] array= {azem, 1 , soaib, 3}; // a[0]= azem , a[1]= 1, a[2]=soaib, a[3]= 3
```

My code is not printing any thing. I also saw ascii table and get the values of numbers in string that is from 48 to 57  but no printing. 
 Mycode:

```
String input = "1"; // integers as input 
//String takeinput;
// String input = "48" + takeinput;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(array[i]== input){
       System.out.print(array[i-1]);
       System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Use array[i].equals(input) method to compare 2 Strings.

Comment: no success. it shd also work when input is integer and prints integer and string that is output: "azem 1"

Comment: @user3440716 Use `.equals()` to compare two `String`s, and you may want to replace you second `System.out.print()` by `System.out.println()` to be sure to show what you are printing.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `==` compares if the two references point to the same object in memory, not whether they actually point to equivalent strings.

Use `array[i].equals(input)` instead.

Comment: not printing anything. but when i remove for loop and if statement and only writes System.out.print(0); it prints.

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
String[] array= {"azem", "1" , "soaib", "3"}; // a[0]= azem , a[1]= 1, a[2]=soaib, a[3]= 3


String input = "1"; // integers as input 
//String takeinput;
// String input = "48" + takeinput;
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].equals(input)) {  // Modified
       System.out.print(array[i-1]);
       System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
```

Or better, if you know every odd position (indexed 0) would be number, you can rewrite the code as,

```
int input = 1; // Modified : integers as input 
for(int i=1; i < array.length; i += 2){
    if(Integer.valueOf(array[i]) == input) {  // Modified
       System.out.println(array[i-1] + ":" + array[i]);
    }
```

This would be a cleaner and a faster solution.

Comment: The array definition will not compile. You have to put everything inside quotes: `String[] array= {"azem", "1" , "soaib", "3"};`

Comment: sorry, I just copied the above code and was concentrating on only     if(array[i].equals(input)) {  // Modified
 line.

Edited. Thanks for the input.

Comment: actually i have taken this string from file and yes it is in this form. but all techniques i applied but no printing

Comment: @user3440716 If it comes from a file, maybe there are some extra characters (like whitespaces), have you tried to `trim()` it ?

Comment: i have done trim. but am near to complete the code by placing user inpts and displayingthe output

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Integer.parseInt(...)` while comparing strings with numeric values?

`Integer.parseInt("26") == Integer.parseInt("56")`

**Update**

You can also try comparing strings with `.equals()` method, as below.

`array[i].equals(input);`

Also, use `println()` instead of `print()` to be sure of what is printing.

Shishir

Comment: if(Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i])== Integer.parseInt("input")){ System.out.print(array[i-1]);
       System.out.print(array[i]); } ; Giving errro